# Clear old messages in Intellij/ pycharm status bar

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

New messages in the `status bar` are continually being overwritten by old `status` messages - in this case *Header does not match expected text...*

[image]

So if newer warnings/errors occur I can not see them after a short (one-two second?) period because that one shown above gets placed on top.

This affects compilation, debugging, and even using `IdeaVim`.

Is there any known solution to this?

Comment: Warnings are shown if caret is placed on highlighted text in editor. Do you get it overwritten even caret is not moved?

Comment: It's not even that simple. It is specifically those *startup* errors that are overwriting all other errors. Those have nothing to do with the caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear and set up what events do you want to see with settings menu.
"Event Log" window you can enable by click on the status bar. I hope it will help you.

1. Clear

[image]

2. Settings menu

[image]

Useful link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/event-log-tool-window.html